# How to count inbox sub-folders including sub-folders under sub-folders and so on in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook

Newbie in need of help. The following code will count all the sub-folders under the inbox but the problem is there are always a number of folders under these sub-folders.  I'm having difficulty working out how to count the sub-folders under the sub-folders if you get my meaning :)

```
MAPIFolder oFolder = this.ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(oRecip, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
int result = oFolder.Folders.Count;
foreach (MAPIFolder subFolder in oFolder.Folders)
   {
       result =+ oFolder.Folders.Count;
   }
tbFolderItemCount.Text = result.ToString();
```

Comment: How would you count the files under a directory including all sub directories? The problem is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the API you are using, but you'll need to switch over to a recursive method. I think it might look something like this:

```
public int CountSubfolders(MAPIFolder folder)
{
    int count = folder.Folders.Count;

    foreach (MAPIFolder subfolder in folder.Folders)
    {
        count += CountSubfolders(subfolder);
    }

    return count;
}
```

And you'd call it with your root folder:

```
MAPIFolder oFolder = this.ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(oRecip, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

int subfolders = CountSubfolders(oFolder);
```